How to get outputDevices list in Qt when a program is run by the root user
My program needs to run in sudo mode on Ubuntu 20.04, then, when I call QAudioDeviceInfo for getting output devises list, it returns an error:

PulseAudioService: pa_context_connect() faild.

In usual user mode, it is ok.
Also, when I run sudo pulseaudio in a terminal, I get:

W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.

and when I call sudo pulseaudio --system in a terminal, I get:

connection failre : access denied


Pulseaudio is normally run from the currently logged in user and only allows programs run as that user. Either configure Pulseaudio to be started as system on startup, or configure it to use a unique socket. In both cases, you must configure your system accordingly, Qt cannot do anything about it. Note that running an audio based program as root is a quite odd requirement, maybe consider explaining that need, as its uncommon and probably unnecessary, if the reason for it is properly addressed.

Not sure about this but, this seems like a system config issue, and not a programming one. If it is, please consider deleting this post and reposting on either Ask Ubuntu or Super User. Make sure you read both of those pages and decide which site is the best suitable for your question. Note that both sites have [tag:qt] and [tag:pulseaudio] tags.

I've checked both sites and found that first I need to run pulseaudio with the command sudo pulseaudio --system. So that I can allow the system to access the audio outputs. Then, when I run my program in Qt and want to read the number of audio outputs, I receive the error "pulseaudioservice: connection failure: Access denied. Otherwise, the system does not have a problem with running pulseaudio by the root user. My program gives an error.

@KosarMohammadzadeh Still, the problem remains: this is not a programming issue, but a system configuration one, which is off topic on SO. If you clarify why you need to run the program as root, then it may be more appropriate and we could eventually address that.

Because I want to read data from pcie, I have to run the program with sudo command.
